# Updating shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: shapefile, merge

I've got a parcels layer from the state and i modified it by adding fields relating to my business as in project number and a reference plan field. The state updated their shapefile by adding new subdivisions. They're all related by oid_1 field which is a parcel id field. some of the polygons have changed and I want to make sure the polygons change and my data fields merge correctly.

Comment: What is your question?  At the moment your question body contains no question mark to indicate what you are asking.

Comment: Basically, what you are saying you have a shapefile for the land parcel that you updated attribute information, you acquired this land parcel shapefile from the state. Now the state has updated its land parcel dataset (new subdivisions), consequently, some geometries or polygons have changed. You now would like to update your information (geometry and attributes)?

Comment: My suggestion would be to take the updated land parcel with updated geometries, overlay it with yours and see which area the polygons have changed. On your shapefile delete the polygons that have changed, on the latest land parcel from the state copy the geometry that changed and pastes it to yours, then update on the attributes for the polygons that have changed instead of recapturing your business information for the entire shapefile.

Comment: Please remember to backup your shapefile when doing edits just in case something does not go right.